# Cross Browser Testing using Coded UI

Tags: cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to run Coded UI tests in chrome. The code is:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
BrowserWindow brw = new BrowserWindow();
brw = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

But I am getting run time error: "value cannot be null.
Parameter name windowhandle".

I have VS2012 Ultimate and have also installed 'Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing'.

Am I doing something wrong or something else needs to be checked?

Comment: Chrome version : 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
ChromeDriver version : 2.25.426923

Answer (score 0):

Created a new Unit Test Project with all Selenium and Browser Drivers. Now I am able to navigate to the URL and run the application.